# Errors installing microsoft-net-sdk-blazorwebassembly-aot in Dockerfile

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to run `dotnet workload install microsoft-net-sdk-blazorwebassembly-aot` from my Dockerfile while building my Blazor project in order to enable AOT WASM compilation.

Here is the relevant Dockerfile code:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal-amd64 AS builder
...
RUN dotnet workload install microsoft-net-sdk-blazorwebassembly-aot
RUN dotnet publish -c Release
```

However, this fails with an error like:

```
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.ios.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.macos.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.tvos.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.android.
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.sdk.ios version 14.5.100-preview.5.894.
Workload installation failed, rolling back installed packs...
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.sdk.ios version 14.5.100-preview.5.881.
Installation roll back failed: Failed to install manifest microsoft.net.sdk.ios version 14.5.100-preview.5.881: The transaction has aborted..
Workload installation failed: Failed to install manifest microsoft.net.sdk.ios version 14.5.100-preview.5.894: Invalid cross-device link.
```

I also tried with `--skip-manifest`, and this appears to install the workload, but then fails to perform the AOT build.

```
RUN dotnet workload install microsoft-net-sdk-blazorwebassembly-aot --skip-manifest-update

Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm version 6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm version 6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5...
...
Garbage collecting for SDK feature bands 6.0.100...

Successfully installed workload(s) microsoft-net-sdk-blazorwebassembly-aot.

RUN dotnet publish -c Release

...
Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  AOT'ing 50 assemblies
/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk/6.0.0-preview.5.21301.5/Sdk/WasmApp.targets(507,5): error MSB3073: The command "emcc --version" exited with code 1.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Morgan, you're hitting two issues:

1. On the skip-manifest (which is the workaround) is issue https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/18450
2. The `emcc --version` error is issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/54342 and resolved by installing Python first...see example: https://github.com/timheuer/PictureFixer/blob/docker/PictureFixer/Dockerfile#L11-L12 (on docker branch in the repo)
3. You will then hit a different bug (could not find cross compiler) which is issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/54651 (which has been checked in).

Once #3 is fixed in an image you can consume, it *should* work ensuring you add #2 in your script.  Example full Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:6.0 AS build 
COPY ["nuget.config", "nuget.config"]
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes python3
RUN dotnet workload install microsoft-net-sdk-blazorwebassembly-aot --skip-manifest-update
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Server/PictureFixer.Server.csproj", "Server/"]
COPY ["Shared/PictureFixer.Shared.csproj", "Shared/"]
COPY ["Client/PictureFixer.Client.csproj", "Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Server/PictureFixer.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Server"
RUN dotnet build "PictureFixer.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build --nologo

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PictureFixer.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --nologo

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PictureFixer.Server.dll"]
```

You can temporarily work around #3 by adding this to your Blazor Wasm project csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <_MonoAotCrossCompilerPath>@(MonoAotCrossCompiler->WithMetadataValue('RuntimeIdentifier','browser-wasm'))</_MonoAotCrossCompilerPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim! Looks like I just needed to install Python, as you said. I didn't run into issue #3, but I'm glad it's already fixed for others who do.